# Type '{}' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intrinsicattributes

I create a dynamic button (Comp) in React TypeScript. "Comp" can be a button, anchor, or Link (React Router). I got a problem with the type having no properties in common with the type `'IntrinsicAttributes'`.

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  href?: string;
  to?: string;

  children: ReactNode;
};

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  const { href, to, children } = props;

  let Comp = 'button';
  if (href) Comp = 'a';
  if (to) Comp = 'Link';

  const compProps = { 
    href,
    to,
  };

  return <Comp {...compProps}>{children}</Comp>;
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; href: string | undefined; to: string | undefined; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559).
```

I researched some pics in StackOverflow but it's not my case.

Comment: You can't use a string as a JSX constructor, `Comp` is not a valid tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass elements as strings, you can use [`React.createElement`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement) for dynamic props with those elements.

*Note that `Link` is not a standard HTML element, so we cannot pass it as a string like `button` and `a`.*

```js
import React, { ReactNode, ElementType } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

type ButtonProps = {
  href?: string;
  to?: string;

  children: ReactNode;
};

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  const { href, to, children } = props;

  let comp: ElementType | typeof Link = 'button';
  if (href) comp = 'a';
  if (to) comp = Link;

  const compProps = { 
    href,
    to,
  };

  return React.createElement(comp, compProps, children);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgKIA2SISAdjACoCeYScAvnAGZQQg4AcigEYQgFChIsXHAAywegGsuvfoIBEo9DAC0-AK4wkUPSQGaJEmGw4AhYzAj0ACvzABnOAF5cEuDgAC1EeAH4ALjhPGCglAHMAbgC4Z0jo2ITklLQg4CoSUXoo5F1iMmTObJ5DegxgFzhHGGd6AAowD08o5tb3CC8ASn9AtBcYuRCkHmxnbFz8woY1P06Bz2zAmngx8CjqWgZmOzgAH1S7CB4FJVU-IQAjJxchZMDga7apnmHdsF9hChXikPnA2s5fgJ-n5FCpNnAxvQJn9+l4AXgUoFvphMakIDjAlVrIFRDBDFB6PhdAA6NA6EwHOiMNp-eZQ1GeeZ5ApFQYSThAA)

Comment: I appreciate your support! I tried and it works.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, could you help me to mark my answer as your solution? that will give me a little support as well as our community. Thank you!~ @HuyPham

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a string as a JSX constructor: `Comp` is not a valid tag.

You can rewrite your code like so:

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  href?: string;
  to?: string;

  children: ReactNode;
};

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  const { href, to, children } = props;

  if (href) return <a href={href}>{children}</a>;
  if (to) return <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>;
  return <button>{children}</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nick Vu's answer. I solved the problem.

```
import React, { ElementType, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';

type ButtonProps = {
  href?: string;
  to?: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

type CompType = ElementType | LinkProps;

function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  const { href, to, children } = props;

  let Comp: CompType = 'button';
  if (href) Comp = 'a';
  if (to) Comp = Link;

  const compProps = {
    href,
    to,
  };

  return <Comp {...compProps}>{children}</Comp>;
}

export default Button;
```